# Drop columns when splitting data frame in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to split data table by column, however once I get list of data tables, they still contains the column which data table was split by. How would I drop this column once the split is complete. Or more preferably, is there a way how do I drop multiple columns.

This is my code:

```
x <- rnorm(10, mean = 5, sd = 2)
y <- rnorm(10, mean = 5, sd = 2)
z <- sample(5, 10, replace = TRUE)
dt <- data.table(x, y, z)

split(dt, dt$z)
```

The resulting data table subsets looks like that

```
$`1`
          x        y z
1: 6.179790 5.776683 1
2: 5.725441 4.896294 1
3: 8.690388 5.394973 1

$`2`
          x        y z
1: 5.768285 3.951733 2
2: 4.572454 5.487236 2

$`3`
          x        y z
1: 5.183101 8.328322 3
2: 2.830511 3.526044 3

$`4`
          x        y z
1: 5.043010 5.566391 4
2: 5.744546 2.780889 4

$`5`
          x          y z
1: 6.771102 0.09301977 5
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems that there's no overload for the split so that could be done in a nice way. However, this seems to be the most optimal solution

Comment: Almost never would you need to do this... I'm curious why you need it split.

Comment: @Arun "Almost never would you need to ask this". The asker certainly has reasons for that. I myself found this very useful because I wanted to analyse the data matrices once they were splt according to the grouping variables.

Answer (score 5):

Splitting a data.table is really not worthwhile unless you have some fancy parallelization step to follow. And even then, you might be better off sticking with a single table.

That said, I think you want

```
split( dt[, !"z"], dt$z )

# or more generally

mysplitDT <- function(x, bycols) 
  split( x[, !..bycols], x[, ..bycols] )

mysplitDT(dt, "z")
```

You would run into the same problem if you had a data.frame:

```
df = data.frame(dt)
split( df[-which(names(df)=="z")], df$z )
```

Comment: I agree, splitting a `data.table` into a list will be (afaik) making many copies from the `data.table`, and would probably not be efficient for large data sets.

Comment: But how would I achieve the following goal then: let's say I have data.table, as defined in my original question, and I want to remove the outliers from each of the group that I could get only by splitting the original data.table.

Comment: @LaurynasStašys  `DT[ ,{ non_outliers <- ...; .SD[ non_outliers ]}, by=z]` where `...` is code using the columns of `DT` to determine rows that are not outliers. data.table is designed to work very well with by-group operations. The introductory materials for the package illustrate its syntax through several examples: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: @LaurynasStašys I am not sure what you want to do exactly for each group in the data. From my experience, you can probably use the `by` argument inside the `data.table`. For example, `dt[, w := sum(x), by = z]` will give you the sum of `x` for each group split by `z`. You will probably want to submit another question with your requirements.

Comment: Oh, basically what @Frank said ;)

Comment: @ialm, what I am trying to do is as following: I have a data.table that contains columns "group" and "value". I am trying to achieve is to remove outliers in each group

Comment: @LaurynasStašys I think you will want to submit a new question with your requirements because there may be many details that require clarification. For example, what constitutes an outlier in your problem? Are you using some outside package to determine outliers? etc. Your new question will not be visible and unlikely to be answered from within a comment chain.

Comment: Exactly, I just thought that I could solve that with my approach, but it seems that another way of doing that is required. Anyway, thanks for your answers!!!

Answer (score 2):

First thing that came to mind was to iterate through the list and drop the `z` column.

`lapply(split(dt, dt$z), function(d) { d$z <- NULL; d })`

And I just noticed that you use the `data.table` package, so there is probably a better, `data.table` way of achieving your desired result.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I also thought of doing. However, I am looking for more neat solution :)